# How to only match elements without a closing tag in regex?

Tags: regex

I am trying to match all XML nodes within a parent node that do not have closing tags.  Does anybody know a regular expression to do so?

Comment: You can't use a regular expression to do this because the regex will not be able to properly handle nested tags .. do you have something against `xmllint` and `tidy`?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: You probably need to modify a parser for this. Apart from not having a closing tag, the tags might be closed incorrectly.

Comment: If I have a piece of XML: `<foo><bar/>Hello World</foo>`, how do I match `<bar/>`?

Answer (score 0):

A simple start:

```
<.*?\/>
```

Note that it will fail with, for example, this:

```
<bar attr="oops/>"/>
```

However, having `/>` in an attribute is a very rare occurence, and you could always escape them.